# FileOpenPicker PickSingleFileAsync throws UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

The following code is almost verbatim from the MSDN example for the [FileOpenPicker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/BR207847?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) class.

```
FileOpenPicker picker = new FileOpenPicker();
picker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
picker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");

StorageFile file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
```

When I trigger it from a button I get the following exception from the last line:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException
>   Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

I thought the idea of the FileOpenPicker in this usage was that I didn't need to ask the user for access permissions or specify any capabilities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I set a breakpoint just before the call to `PickSingleFileAsync()`. Turns out that two tapped events were being fired when pressing a TextBlock within a Border (both with the same Tapped event handler).

The first call worked as expected, but subsequent call resulted in the UnauthorizedAccessException and would occur straight after the picker was displayed.