# Always getting " Access is denied" while calling FileOpenPicker.PickSingleFileAndContinue()

Tags: c#

I am getting stuck while invoking  FileOpenPicker.PickSingleFileAndContinue when coding for my WP 8.1 application. What I did is simply run following code in OnLoaded method in my class which is inherited from Page class.

```
FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.List;
openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".pdf");
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".PDF");
openPicker.PickSingleFileAndContinue();
```

And after invoking the PickSingleFileAndContinue() method, an exception with following message was always thrown out:

> "System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))\r\n   at
>   Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker.PickSingleFileAndContinue()

I may did something wrong with the code, but where. Any one got my appreciation for any help. Thank you.

Comment: Try checking this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15493455/fileopenpicker-picksinglefileasync-throws-unauthorizedaccessexception

Comment: Thank you Soner, but no, these are two different cases. I just double confirmed that the method was invoked only once. And the issue in that post occurred on Win 8/8.1 platform, not WP 8.1. Any way, thank you for trying help.

Answer (score 5):

Answer from MSDN:

```
Your FileOpenPicker code is fine. 
The problem is that you can't call it from your page load.
If you delay it a bit or (better) call it in response to user
action then your code snippet will work.
```

And this solves the problem.